# Consultar el nombre y topic de los artículos de menor duración

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: tablas de midata]

Esas son las dos tablas de mi base de datos.  Se requiere obtener el nombre y el topic de los artículos de menor duración.

Cómo hago esa consulta?

Llevo esto:

```
select paper.paper_name,paper.topic 
from introduce 
inner join introduce on paper.paper_code=introduce.paper_code;
```

> Debe traerme por ejemplo el nombre y topic de los que tuvieron las duraciones de 45 y 60

Comment: select paper.paper_name,paper.topic from introduce inner join introduce on paper.paper_code=introduce.paper_code;

Comment: Debe traerme por ejemplo el nombre y topic de los que tuvieron las duraciones de 45 y 60.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacer uso de un **`JOIN`** para encontrar la vinculación entre la tabla *papers* y la tabla *introduce*, es decir igualar la llave primaria de una con la llave foránea de la otra.

Por otro lado requieres filtrar y para ello emplearás **`WHERE`** estableciendo la columna y usando algún operador de comparación o igualación para determinarlo.

El filtro se construye indicando que la columna **`duration`** sea igual a uno u otro valor eso lo logramos con el operador **`OR`** para que en cualquier renglón donde coincida con 45 o 60 sean los valores retornados

```
SELECT paper.paper_name,
       paper.topic
FROM paper
INNER JOIN introduce ON paper.paper_code = introduce.paper_code
WHERE introduce.duration = 45 OR introduce.duration = 60;
```

O bien la línea del **`WHERE`** puede quedar de esta forma:

```
WHERE introduce.duration IN (45, 60);
```

Si los valores no son fijos pues entonces lo único que se me ocurre para editar la pregunta es:

```
SELECT paper.paper_name,
       paper.topic
FROM paper
INNER JOIN introduce ON paper.paper_code = introduce.paper_code
ORDER BY introduce.duration LIMIT algo
```

Donde algo será la cantidad de valores a tomar de los renglones devueltos (al momento no se me ocurre mas)

Comment: Y si los valores no son 45 y 60? Es decir, pide que me devuelva los de menor duración, sin importar si estos cambian.  Si yo los cambio a 10 y 20 (por ejemplo), ya no me serviría, cómo implemento lo del min() ?

Comment: "Lo que se pide" está claro, dice: Se requiere obtener el nombre y el topic de los artículos de menor duración.  Cuando dice de "menor duración", automáticamente te indica que no son en base a valores fijos, sino que son dinámicos como tú mismo lo dices.  Por cierto, soy novato en el desarrollo de software, pero no en la vida.  Gracias por tus apreciaciones.  Como consejo, 'procura' leer para interpretar mejor.